# how to get content of async script tag using Xpath

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xpath, jdom

I am trying to get the script tag content using xpath (using java org.jdom2 package)but its a async script and I am not getting any content .

The tag is something like  below
 script src="https:wwww.xyz" async="" type="text/javascript">/script

I tried using the Xapth  page.getNode(//body/script[@type='text/javascript'])
I know there will be many script tags but for now please assume we have only one .

After going through similar posts I got to know that async calls take time to get loaded and the browser delays loading it.Any leads on how to know a document is done loading using org.jdom2 (I am  not using any  javascript or selenium )

Answer (score 0):

This: *I am trying to get the script tag content*

Is not possible.

> ***What is JDOM not?***
>
> JDOM is not a wrapper for the W3C's DOM, or another version of DOM.

2 Points:

1. JDOM does not *parse* the XHTML into a DOM, it constructs an XML tree that represents the structure of DOM. Since there is no *parsing*, there is no way of *loading* anything.
2. Even if the JavaScript was loaded for that tag (using SAX or other DOM parser), you would not be able to parse it (*get the script tag content*) with XPath in this fashion because it is an external resource (file).

Comment: What if I Just want to get the attribute value of "src" here ?.The script tag itself is not getting loaded since it's async..while srcipt tags with no async attribute get fetched

Comment: The `src` attribute value is available to you via XPATH naturally. Just query for it.